# Pandas returning empty dataframe after merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to merge multiple sets of word data. Each csv file that is read in (there is 4 files) contains a column for each unique word in a book, and a column for how many times that word shows up. Whats supposed to happen is the word columns of all of these csv files are supposed to merge into one in this new matrix file I'm trying to create, but when I attempt to merge each csv file and its data, an empty data frame is returned.

The csv files are like:

```
Word Count
Thou   100
O      20
Hither 8
```

and I want them to merge like this:

```
Word  Book1  Book2 Book3
Thou   50     0      88
Hello  32     35     27
No     89     38      0
Yes    80     99       0
```

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

import pandas as pd

dataPath = 'data/'
fileNames = [f for f in listdir(dataPath) if isfile(join(dataPath, f))]
columns = [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in fileNames]
columns.remove('rows')
columns.remove('cols')
columns.remove('matrix')
columns.insert(0, "Word")
wordData = []
matrix = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)



for file in fileNames:
    if '.txt' in file:
        continue
    elif 'matrix' in file:
        continue
    else:
        myFile = open(f"./data/{file}", "r")
        readFile = myFile.read()
        dataVector = pd.read_csv(f"./data/{file}", sep=",")
        #print(dataVector)
        matrix.merge(dataVector, how="outer", on=["Word"])
        print(matrix)
        myFile.close()


pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
matrix = matrix.fillna(0)
matrix.to_csv(path_or_buf="./data/matrix.csv")
```

Comment: You are doing `matrix.merge(dataVector, ...)`. However, `pandas.DataFrame.merge` returns a merged DataFrame. It does not merge `inplace`.

Comment: @J.Choi When I don't do it inline, it puts all the data in 2 columns, but I need each dataVector to be in its own column and have the word columns merge.

Comment: I think it would be better to post [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with an expected output.

Comment: @J.Choi Just posted something at the top.

Comment: `it puts all the data in 2 columns` That might be because the column name is `count` for all so when you merge it's merging in that column only. Try changing column name to `book1, book2` etc and then merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be the thing you needed.

Data:

```
import pandas as pd

book_list = []
book_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'Word': ['a', 'b'], 'Count': [1, 2]}))
book_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'Word': ['b', 'c'], 'Count': [3, 4]}))
book_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'Word': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'Count': [5, 6, 7]}))
book_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'Word': ['c', 'e'], 'Count': [8, 9]}))
```

Code:

```
result = None
for idx_book, book in enumerate(book_list):
    if result is None:
        result = book
    else:
        result = result.merge(book, how="outer", on=["Word"], suffixes=(idx_book-1, idx_book))
```

Result:

```
    Word    Count0  Count1  Count2  Count3
0   a   1.0 NaN NaN NaN
1   b   2.0 3.0 NaN NaN
2   c   NaN 4.0 NaN 8.0
3   d   NaN NaN 5.0 NaN
4   e   NaN NaN 6.0 9.0
5   f   NaN NaN 7.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving it by using this lambda function:
`matrix = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Word'],how='outer'), wordData).fillna(0)`